# Android - Unable to play audio during boot animation

Tags: android, boot-animation

I am trying to add audio during boot animation in android device. But I heard static noise instead added audio.

I added audio.wav file in part folder, as mentioned in this page.

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/bootanimation/FORMAT.md.

frameworks/base/cmds/bootanimation/
```

Initially,  I had an issue in creating the audio player. I got the below error.

```
This structure has default values from Google AOSP. I haven't modified. 
SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {
        SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM,
        2,
        44100000,  // convert to milliHz
        32,
        16,
        3,
        SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN
    }
```

**01-31 17:51:54.155  6632  6644 W libOpenSLES: Leaving Engine::CreateAudioPlayer (SL_RESULT_PARAMETER_INVALID)
01-31 17:51:54.155  6632  6644 E audioplay: sl CreateAudioPlayer failed with result 2**

I have read one post, and changed the sturcture values as below. After that audio player was created successfully, and static noise was heard.

```
SLDataFormat_PCM pcm;
pcm.formatType = SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM;
pcm.numChannels = 2;
pcm.samplesPerSec = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_8;
pcm.bitsPerSample = SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16;
pcm.containerSize = SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16;
pcm.channelMask = SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT;
pcm.endianness = SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN;
```

If anyhow has experienced similar issue, please provide some inputs on this.

Comment: Could you characterize the static noise? Was it loud, and continuous, or spotty? How long did it last, compared to the length of the .wav file?

Comment: Duration of the noise matches to the wav file duration, and it is not loud.

Comment: Try switching the endianness of the file or the player.